# Docker :after add --privileged, docker return error

Tags: linux, docker, systemctl

[github issure](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1351)

**Because I removed a running container dir manually at /var/lib/docker/containers by mistake, then --privileged return error.
But it worked without --privileged.**

```
$ docker run -d --name=hello --privileged=true hello-world                                                
fd6cdf95eb1ed7617f4580eef556a2f64fff7b9afb144d346af3916d83704de4
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: unable to apply cgroup configuration: chown /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/docker-fd6cdf95eb1ed7617f4580eef556a2f64fff7b9afb144d346af3916d83704de4.scope/memory.oom.group: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

systemctl log:

```
1月 27 14:30:28 pi dockerd[630408]: time="2022-01-27T14:30:28.182022716+08:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/3a42ea697432d31ffa04730b321526da2cb8e9490f9fc6edb68dda623e5bfa2c pid=645804
1月 27 14:30:28 pi dockerd[630408]: time="2022-01-27T14:30:28.434396893+08:00" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=3a42ea697432d31ffa04730b321526da2cb8e9490f9fc6edb68dda623e5bfa2c
1月 27 14:30:28 pi dockerd[630408]: time="2022-01-27T14:30:28.434794719+08:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=3a42ea697432d31ffa04730b321526da2cb8e9490f9fc6edb68dda623e5bfa2c namespace=moby
1月 27 14:30:28 pi dockerd[630408]: time="2022-01-27T14:30:28.434912272+08:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
1月 27 14:30:28 pi dockerd[630408]: time="2022-01-27T14:30:28.492815104+08:00" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2022-01-27T14:30:28+08:00\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=645826\n"
1月 27 14:30:28 pi dockerd[630408]: time="2022-01-27T14:30:28.494742125+08:00" level=error msg="copy shim log" error="read /proc/self/fd/25: file already closed"
1月 27 14:30:28 pi dockerd[630400]: time="2022-01-27T14:30:28.501658261+08:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
1月 27 14:30:28 pi dockerd[630400]: time="2022-01-27T14:30:28.501842720+08:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
1月 27 14:30:28 pi dockerd[630400]: time="2022-01-27T14:30:28.931391572+08:00" level=error msg="3a42ea697432d31ffa04730b321526da2cb8e9490f9fc6edb68dda623e5bfa2c cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
```

docker version:

```
docker version                                                                                           [9:53:58]
Client:
 Version:           20.10.12
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.5
 Git commit:        e91ed5707e
 Built:             Tue Dec 14 20:49:29 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.12
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.5
  Git commit:       459d0dfbbb
  Built:            Tue Dec 14 20:48:54 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.5.9
  GitCommit:        1407cab509ff0d96baa4f0eb6ff9980270e6e620.m
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.0
  GitCommit:        v1.1.0-0-g067aaf85
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: If you corrupted the `/var/lib/docker/containers` tree, a good approach could be to stop Docker, remove all of `/var/lib/docker` (except perhaps the `volumes` subdirectory), and start again.  You'll have to re-build/pull your images and restart your containers but this should be something you can do starting from your source control system.

Comment: I've tried uninstall docker ,remove /var/lib/docker, and reinstall docker.I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I create a normal container, it works, but there is a caveat:`Your kernel does not support memory limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted.`.

So I added `cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1` at the end of the `/boot/cmdline.txt` and reboot.

And then all my problems were solved, although I still don't know why.

Comment: Before solved, I tried uninstalling docker and containerd, remove all folders containing "docker*" "containerd*".It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to install docker from another host and copy the `/usr/bin/runc` file to the host with the problem

Comment: $ ll /usr/bin/runc                                                                                        
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11M  1月 18 08:22 /usr/bin/runc
This file date is earlier than the problem date, I don't think this will work.

Comment: Before I delete the container dir by mistake,--privileged can work normally